# Add active class to current element only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some repeating content sections with a button within them. On click of the button, I wish to add an active class to the 'content' div. However rather than apply the active class to all instances, I wish it to target only the content div within the same row as the button that has been clicked.

```
<div id="1" class="row">
    <button class="click-me"></button>
    <div class="content">I want the active class applied within this div only.</div>
</div>

<div id="2" class="row">
    <button class="click-me"></button>
    <div class="content">I want the active class applied within this div only.</div>
</div>

<div id="3" class="row">
    <button class="click-me"></button>
    <div class="content">I want the active class applied within this div only.</div>
</div>
```

I have got some JS which adds the class but unfortunately applies to to every instance. How can I adjust this to apply to the current row only?

My JS is currently:

```
$(function swatchClass() {
    $('.click-me').click(function() { // when a .myDiv is clicked
        $('.content').not(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this. In case you also want to toggle the class `active` for the div with the class `content`, just use `toggleClass()` instead of `addClass()`.

```js
$(function swatchClass() {
    $('.click-me').click(function() { 
        $(this).closest(".row").find(".content").addClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1" class="row">
  <button class="click-me">Click</button>
  <div class="content">I want the active class applied within this div only.</div>
</div>

<div id="2" class="row">
  <button class="click-me">Click</button>
  <div class="content">I want the active class applied within this div only.</div>
</div>

<div id="3" class="row">
  <button class="click-me">Click</button>
  <div class="content">I want the active class applied within this div only.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to achieve... I was missing the .find() element. Thank you so much for your help :)